# Python 3.6 Pandas Difflib Get_Close_Matches to filter a dataframe with user input

Tags: pandas, match, python-3.6, difflib

Using a csv imported using a pandas dataframe, I am trying to search one column of the df for entries similar to a user generated input.  Never used difflib before and my tries have ended in a TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() or an empty [] list.

```
import difflib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Vendorlist.csv", encoding= "ISO-8859-1")
word = input ("Enter a vendor: ")

def find_it(w):
    w = w.lower()
    return difflib.get_close_matches(w, df.vendorname, n=50, cutoff=.6)

alternatives = find_it(word)
print (alternatives)
```

The error seems to occur at "return.difflib.get_close_matches(w, df.vendorname, n=50, cutoff=.6)"

Am attempting to get similar results to "word" with a column called 'vendorname'.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column `vendorname` is of the incorrect type.

Try in your return statement:

```
return difflib.get_close_matches(w, df.vendorname.astype(str), n=50, cutoff=.6)
```

---

```
import difflib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Vendorlist.csv", encoding= "ISO-8859-1")
word = input ("Enter a vendor: ")

def find_it(w):
    w = w.lower()
    return difflib.get_close_matches(w, df.vendorname.astype(str), n=50, cutoff=.6)

alternatives = find_it(word)
print (alternatives)
```

---

As stated in the comments by @johnchase

> The question also mentions the return of an empty list. The return of get_close_matches is a list of matches, if no item matched within the cutoff an empty list will be returned – johnchase

Comment: The question also mentions the return of an empty list. The return of `get_close_matches` is a list of matches, if no item matched within the cutoff an empty list will be returned

Comment: The ".astype(str)" was what I was missing.  That works.  Also your second point had me double check and all the entries are in upper case not lower case so I changed the code to "w = w.upper()"

Answer (score -1):

I've skipped the:

```
astype(str)in (return difflib.get_close_matches(w, df.vendorname.astype(str), n=50, cutoff=.6))
```

Instead used:

```
dtype='string' in (df = pd.read_csv("Vendorlist.csv", encoding= "ISO-8859-1"))
```